# How restart Mediaplayer when i return to activity

Tags: android, lifecycle

I 'm developing an app with music . but when I go to another activity and then go back to the previous one, the music does not start again , why?

```
 public class MaximosRegistros extends Activity {

ListView lista;
BaseDeDatos bd;
Vector<String> maxRegis;
MediaPlayer sonidoJuego;
Boolean sonido;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
String puntos;
int pos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maximos_registros);
    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    maxRegis= new Vector<String>();
    bd= new BaseDeDatos(this);
    maxRegis=bd.listaPuntos(10);
    TodoAdapter adaptador= new TodoAdapter(this,maxRegis);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            pos=position;
            return false;
        }

    });
    registerForContextMenu(lista);
 }
 @Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();

    sonidoJuego.start();
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.compartir:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EnviarPuntuacion.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        break;

    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

}
```

And i tried with onStart(), onPause(), onResume() but it nothing works.
Help me!!

Comment: Where are you initializing your `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: i make a MediaPlayer object but i think that i is not inizializing.It has something to do with it?

Comment: oh yes yes it is this? sonidoJuego=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.registros);